# How to know if arduino activated its short breaker?

Tags: arduino-uno

today i was trying to use arduino power headers as a power source for my basic laser.
I used pin "5V" to connect it to the laser anode and the "GND" pin to the laser groung pin.
after doing this arduino turned restarted, so I removed all the connections to the laser, now the arduino is normal.
booth "5V" and "GND" pins is working normal.
does this mean that I made a short circut and arduino protected it self ?
should I do anything now ?

Comment: What's the rated current and voltage for your laser?  Laser diodes, like LEDs, typically need a constant-current controller (or a properly sized series resistor).  Eg a red LD might use about 200 mA and develop a voltage of about 2.35 V.  Putting 5 V straight into it may ruin it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like connecting your Laser to the 5 volts power supply did draw too much current, thereby the 5 volts dropped to very low voltage.

The Arduino didn't "protect" itself.  The Arduino simply shut down because of voltage being too low. Then, upon reapplication of 5 volts the Arduino re-started as normal.

You don't mention any details about the Laser.  But if your Laser is simply a Diode, the Laser diode would draw a lot of current, resulting in the 5 volts power source giving reduced voltage.

If your Laser is a "laser module" with a built in driver, perhaps you connected the Laser backwards to the 5 volts.

EDIT 11/20/2015 :  IF you are using the Arduino UNO ,  : The  PolyFuse only protects from 500 mA overload on the USB connector.  Schematic for the UNO shows that 5 volts for USB is called "XUSB". The  PolyFuse connects from "USB VCC" to the XUSB.  When you connected your Laser to the +5 and ground, the  PolyFuse was not involved. (Unless of course you did connect to the USB 5 volts (XUSB), and didn't tell us that.

HOWEVER,  if you powered your UNO from the USB port, then the  PolyFuse WAS involved and did shut you down as others have commented.

Answer (score 1):

You uses more the 500mA limit, and the PolyFuse tripped. After unplugging the polyfuse cooled down and "reset" itself.